# How to check if a string is empty in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to write an if statement that will do something base on whether a string is empty.  For example:

```
(defun prepend-dot-if-not-empty (user-str)
   (interactive "s")
   (if (is-empty user-str)
     (setq user-str (concat "." user-str)))
   (message user-str))
```

In this contrived example, I'm using (is-empty) in place of the real elisp method.  What is the right way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is better rewritten to `(message "%s" (if (is-empty user-str) "." user-str))`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since in elisp, a String is an int array, you can use

```
(= (length user-str) 0)
```

You can also use (string=) which is usually easier to read

```
(string= "" user-str)
```

Equal works as well, but a bit slower:

```
(equal "" user-str)
```

Comment: Are you *sure* `equal` is slower?  Last time I looked at this (many years ago), it was somewhere between "identicall" and "a bit faster".

Answer (score 9):

Starting in emacs 24.4, there are two different functions available for you to call, depending on what you mean by 'empty'.

```
(string-empty-p " ")
nil

(string-blank-p " ")
0
```

I'm having trouble finding docs to link to, but [emacsredux.com](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/02/02/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-new-string-manipulation-functions/) has more information.

If you get the error `Symbol's function definition is void.`, include `(require 'subr-x)` in the initialization file (it's a package for trimming and string manipulation).

Comment: I have Emacs 26.3 and both calls throw `Symbol's function definition is void.`

Comment: @miguelmorin: Try putting `(require 'subr-x)` somewhere earlier in your file. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you work with strings heavily in your code, i strongly recommend using Magnar Sveen's [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) string manipulation library.

[`s-blank?`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-blank-s) checks if the string is empty:

```
(s-blank? "") ; => t
```

Answer (score 6):

I keep this one in my `utils.lisp`:

```lisp
(defun empty-string-p (string)
  "Return true if the STRING is empty or nil. Expects string type."
  (or (null string)
      (zerop (length (string-trim string)))))
```

then I do:

```lisp
(not (empty-string-p some-string))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the canonical way of testing this is, but you could use the length function and check to see if your string's length is greater than zero:

```
(length "abc")  
=> 3
(length "")  
=> 0
```

The EmacsWiki elisp cookbook has [an example of a trim function](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook) if you want to remove whitespace before testing.